# Checking file size always

Tags: java, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of folder or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/size-of-folder-or-file)

How to do such a loop that will check the file size, and if it change then output something ? Not only once, but every time to show something if the size change

Comment: So you want to monitor it, long-term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 7 has support for this without polling the file system see [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes)