# How to get file size in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of folder or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/size-of-folder-or-file)

I used this code to instantiate a `File` object:

```
File f = new File(path);
```

How do I get the size of this file?

What is the difference between `getUsableSpace()`, `getTotalSpace()`, and `getFreeSpace()`?

Comment: did you even *try* to search to an existing question that answered your question?

Comment: Depends; in the central or eastern regions, use Javanese; in the rest, use Indonesian. Most Javanese speakers (except outliers) also speak Indonesian though. Wait, what?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Use the [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length--) method in the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class. From the javadocs:

> Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname. The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.

**UPDATED** Nowadays we should use the [`Files.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#size(java.nio.file.Path)) method:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/file");
long size = Files.size(path);
```

For the second part of the question, straight from `File`'s javadocs:

- `getUsableSpace()` Returns the number of bytes available to this virtual machine on the partition named by this abstract pathname
- `getTotalSpace()` Returns the size of the partition named by this abstract pathname
- `getFreeSpace()` Returns the number of unallocated bytes in the partition named by this abstract path name

Comment: This answer is a now outdated; the File API has been replaced with the new API, where it'd be: `Paths path = Paths.get("/path/to/file"); long size = Files.size(path);` See [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#size(java.nio.file.Path)).

Comment: @rzwitserloot thank you! I updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: oh, fantastic. I never know how to deal with great answers which have been overtaken by time. But, hey, if the original author is around to update things, so much the better. Gracias!

Answer (score 44):

Try this:

```
long length = f.length();
```

Answer (score 17):

Did a quick google.  Seems that to find the file size you do this,

```
long size = f.length();
```

The differences between the three methods you posted can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0100__File-Stream/Get_free_space_total_space_usable_space.htm)

getFreeSpace() and getTotalSpace() are pretty self explanatory, getUsableSpace() seems to be the space that the JVM can use, which in most cases will be the same as the amount of free space.

Comment: **I found this code in this site only: and is very useful**  
        public static long folderSize(File directory) {    
           long length = 0;  
            for (File file : directory.listFiles()) { 
             if (file.isFile())
             length += file.length();  
              else  
              length += folderSize(file);  
          } 
           return length;  
    }