# How to obtain file name and file size by improving provided Java code

Tags: java, servlets

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
    List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory())
            .parseRequest(request);
    for(FileItem item : multiparts) {
        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
            item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
            String fname = name;
        }
    }
```

How do I obtain the file name and file size in a JSP page from this servlet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file size in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721262/how-to-get-file-size-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of folder or file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/get-size-of-folder-or-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `item.getSize()` to get file size . You already have the filename.
Alternatively you can use this to get filename

```
String fileName = item.getName();
if (fileName != null) {
    filename = FilenameUtils.getName(filename);
}
```

To pass this to JSP use `response.setAttribute` or session attributes.

Comment: yeah you are right i already have a filename....still i cant get a file size......

Comment: use getSize() as suggested.

Comment: another problem,item.getsize() retrieves numbers like 123543 like this.i need to get filesize like a 12kbs, 2mb something like that

Comment: The size is in bytes. Divide it by 1024 to get size in kB.