# How to get the file size of a downloaded file using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

How to get the file size of a downloaded file of specific name using the Selenium Web Driver ?? Please Help

Comment: Open a search engine and search for "how to get file size with Java". This is nothing Selenium-specific.

Comment: @Tirthankar it may be duplicated question. This is not related with selenium. You can take the help from the link [How to get file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721262/how-to-get-file-size-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
long fileLength = conn.getContentLengthLong();
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Java**

you can do it with just two lines of code.

```
File file = new File("path//to//your//file.txt");
System.out.println(file.length());
```