# How to check that the directory is mounted and available?

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, network-programming, mount

Folder on the server is mounted as follows:

root@ubuntusrv:/mnt# mount -t cifs //192.168.14.12/share -o auto,user,iocharset=utf8,uid=1001,umask=000,username=john,password=smith /mnt/target

or so:

root@ubuntusrv:/mnt# mount -t cifs //192.168.14.12/share -o username=john,password=smith /mnt/target

How in Java web app to check that the folder /mnt/target mounted and available now?

Answer (score 2):

The answer:

```
File f = new File("/mnt/target/some_existing_dir);
f.exists();
```

Something that does not depend on directory content might require native/OS dependant code. You can always execute mount command and filter output to find out if your directory is mounted or not.

Answer (score 1):

Better is to check the folder size, as directory into where them remote file-system is mounted exists anyway. Better to check the size if the size is more or less the expected one as mounted folder is usually large for additional storage.

[Link on checking folder size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/size-of-folder-or-file):