# Java - Adding login in for loop

Tags: java

```
long total = 0L;
for(File f : files)
{
    //how to add?
}
```

Here is my code. I wanna to get the size of directorys inside a directory. Does anyone have idea about how to do that?

Comment: And what is the relation between login and files size ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please try to do a little research before posting a question. There is a high likelihood someone has asked it already.

Comment: @Salah probably to display how much data is left in their account

Comment: +1 for anticipating > 2GB with `long`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/size-of-folder-or-file here u go.. there are already simmilar questions

Comment: Okay everyone. I know how to get the size of directory. I just don't know how to find the TOTAL size of the directory. Please read my question before answering me stupid question.

Comment: Question solved. To add the `long`, use `long_a += size`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of directory by using `common.io` package:

```
long size = sizeOfDirectory(File directory);
```

Counts the size of a directory recursively (sum of the length of all files).