# Java - scan folder and return file sizes by file type

Tags: java, file, recursion

Lets say I want to scan a folder that has 4 - .xlsx files, 8 -.docx files, 10 - .pdfs, and 4 .pptx files. I want my output to not only include the breakdown of files, but also the sum of the sizes of all them put together.

Example Output  
File Type | # of Files | Sum of Files sizes (in MB) 
.xlsx | 4 | 32 
.docx | 8 | 85

I have found some other code that finds and returns the files based on extensions, and so I am just wondering if there is some java code that finds file sizes? I apologize if I am not clear...

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you searched a bit? Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/get-size-of-folder-or-file

Comment: My apologies for not taking the time to search a little deeper into stackoverflow. I appreciate the direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a method that you can use recursively (or not) on you directory

```
private static HashMap<String, Long> sizesForDirectory(String directory, boolean recurseInSubDirectories) {
    File folder = new File(directory);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    HashMap<String, Long> sizesByExtension = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    if (listOfFiles != null) {
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                String extension = file.getName().replaceAll(".*\\.", "");
                if (sizesByExtension.containsKey(extension)) {
                    Long size = sizesByExtension.get(extension) + Long.valueOf(file.length());
                    sizesByExtension.put(extension, size);
                } else {
                    sizesByExtension.put(extension, file.length());
                }
            } else if (recurseInSubDirectories) {
                HashMap<String, Long> sizesForSubdirectory = sizesForDirectory(file.getAbsolutePath(), recurseInSubDirectories);
                for (String ext : sizesForSubdirectory.keySet()) {
                    if (sizesByExtension.containsKey(ext)) {
                        sizesByExtension.put(ext, sizesByExtension.get(ext) + sizesForSubdirectory.get(ext));
                    } else {
                        sizesByExtension.put(ext, sizesForSubdirectory.get(ext));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sizesByExtension;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Long> sizesByExtension = sizesForDirectory("your/path", true);

    for (String ext : sizesByExtension.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(ext + " : " + sizesByExtension.get(ext));
    }

}
```

Comment: This is getting very close! -- This seems to only go through one folder -- I want it to go through an entire directory of folders and return sizes per file type..

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a method that recurse through a directory instead of listing just the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the 'length' of the File object.

```
import java.io.File;

File file = new File(<filepath>);
int sizeInBytes = file.length();
```

You should be able to integrate the summation of sizes fairly easily if you already have a working solution that counts files of a certain type.