# Downloading a file from spring controllers

Tags: java, spring, file, download, controller

I have a requirement where I need to download a PDF from the website. The PDF needs to be generated within the code, which I thought would be a combination of a freemarker and a PDF generation framework like `iText`. Is there any better way?

However, my main problem is how do I allow the users to download the file through a Spring Controller?

Comment: It worth mentioning that Spring Framework changed a lot since 2011, so you can do it in a reactive way as well - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46766566/2004186) is an example

Comment: With later versions of spring, you just need to return the byte array with appropriate headers in ResponseEntity. Here is a full example: https://allaboutspringframework.com/java-spring-download-file-from-controller/

Answer (score 435, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(
    @PathVariable("file_name") String fileName, 
    HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
      // get your file as InputStream
      InputStream is = ...;
      // copy it to response's OutputStream
      org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
      response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '{}'", fileName, ex);
      throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }

}
```

Generally speaking, when you have `response.getOutputStream()`, you can write anything there. You can pass this output stream as a place to put generated PDF to your generator. Also, if you know what file type you are sending, you can set

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was about to say, but you should probably also set the response type header to something appropriate for the file.

Comment: Yep, just edited the post. I had various file types generated, so I left it to the browser to determine the content type of the file by its extension.

Comment: Forgot the flushBuffer, thanks to your post, I saw why mine wasn't working :-)

Comment: Remember to close InputStream.

Comment: Any particular reason to use Apache's `IOUtils` instead of Spring's `FileCopyUtils`?

Comment: Normally yes you close your streams. In this case, though, I think not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter

Comment: Can I set the file name? I'm actually interested in the file extension like .pdf or .csv

Comment: @Gevorg look lobster1234 answer, you can set the header of the response and put any filename you want (the client will get).

Comment: Here is a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc

Comment: @Infeligo, i use these code, but my chrome not show a download link for the file. how can i do then?

Comment: Same here. Blank PDFs.

Comment: Be careful with `response.flushBuffer()`! If your Controller is `@Transactional`, it will send a response even if the transaction should be rolled back, which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: @Powerlord Spring method closes the streams, Apache one does not. There are debates if the Servlet response output stream should be closed in the Controller code or by the Servlet container ...

Answer (score 307):

I was able to stream line this by using the built in support in Spring with it's ResourceHttpMessageConverter.  This will set the content-length and content-type if it can determine the mime-type

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName) {
    return new FileSystemResource(myService.getFileFor(fileName)); 
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best & most clean way of handling file requests.

Comment: absolutely the best response see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated for pathvariable being truncated (spring 3.0.7 in my case)

Comment: This method looks great but can't get it to work 100%. I don't want to open a question for this but on the off chance someone can help. I can't seem to set any details on what is returned such as the file name. Also on good old IE7 & IE8 the file extension seems to get lost somehow so it doesn't even know what file type is being downloaded. Does anyone have some useful example explaining the usage of this to a Spring noob. I'm currently just using HttpServletResponse but would like to use the above method if I could get to send back a little more details in the response.

Comment: This works. But the file (.csv file) is displayed in the browser and not downloaded - how can I force the browser to download?

Comment: You can add produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE to the @RequestMapping to force download

Comment: Also You should add **<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>** to messageConverters list (<mvc:annotation-driven><mvc:message-converters>)

Comment: And can you set content-type with this method?

Comment: ClassPathResource is a nice alternative to FileSystemResource.

Comment: Is there a way to set the `Content-Disposition` header with this way?

Comment: I didn't have a need for that, but I think you could add HttpResponse as a parameter to the method, and then "response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=somefile.pdf");"

Comment: @ScottCarlson Can i create a custom class and extend from `FileSystemResource` and use that class type as return type of download controller?

Comment: I like this way more than @Infeligo's one but if the file doesn't exist, this doesn't throw any exception and the client download hangs forever (until client times out). Is there something wrong in the builtin ResourceHttpMessageConverter?

Comment: To answer myself: it seems ResourceHttpMessageConverter silently discards Exceptions for some reasons related to SPR-12999 and SPR-13620. To get what I want (an error if the file does not exist or some other error happens trying to stream the file) I had to write a custom converter extending ResourceHttpMessageConverter (overwriting writeContent) and a custom web config extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (overwriting configureMessageConverters).

Comment: what is myService?

Answer (score 88):

You should be able to write the file on the response directly. Something like

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");      
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"somefile.pdf\"");
```

and then write the file as a binary stream on `response.getOutputStream()`. Remember to do `response.flush()` at the end and that should do it.

Comment: isn't the 'Spring' way to set the content type like this? `@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar", produces = "application/pdf")`

Comment: @Francis what if your application downloads different file types? Lobster1234's answer enables you to dynamically set the content disposition.

Comment: that's true @Rose, but I believe it would be better practice to define different end-points per format

Comment: I guess not, because it's not scalable. We are currently supporting a dozen types of resources. We might support more file types based on what users want to upload in that case we might end up with so many end points essentially doing the same thing. IMHO there has to be only one download end point and it handles multitude of file types. @Francis

Comment: it's absolutely "scalable", but we can agree to disagree whether it's the best practice

Answer (score 83):

With Spring 3.0 you can use the `HttpEntity` return object. If you use this, then your controller does not need a `HttpServletResponse` object, and therefore it is easier to test. 
*Except this, this answer is relative equals to the one of Infeligo*.

If the return value of your pdf framework is an byte array *(read the second part of my answer for other return values)* :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<byte[]> createPdf(
                 @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {

    byte[] documentBody = this.pdfFramework.createPdf(filename);

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                   "attachment; filename=" + fileName.replace(" ", "_"));
    header.setContentLength(documentBody.length);

    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(documentBody, header);
}
```

---

**If the return type of your PDF Framework (`documentBbody`) is not already a byte array** (and also no `ByteArrayInputStream`) then it would been wise **NOT** to make it a byte array first. Instead it is better to use:

- [`InputStreamResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html),
- [`PathResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/PathResource.html) (since Spring 4.0) or
- [`FileSystemResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html),

example with `FileSystemResource`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<byte[]> createPdf(
                 @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {

    File document = this.pdfFramework.createPdf(filename);

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                   "attachment; filename=" + fileName.replace(" ", "_"));
    header.setContentLength(document.length());

    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(new FileSystemResource(document),
                                  header);
}
```

Comment: -1 this will un-neccessarily load the whole file in memory can easily casue OutOfMemoryErrors.

Comment: @FaisalFeroz: yes this is right, but the file document is anyway created in memory (see the question: "PDF needs to be generated within the code"). Anyway - what is your solution that overcome this problem?

Comment: You may also use ResponseEntity which is a super of HttpEntity which allows you to specify the response http status code. Example: `return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(documentBody, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED)`

Comment: @Amr Mostafa: `ResponseEntity` is a subclass of `HttpEntity` (but I get it) on the other hand 201 CREATED is not what I would use when I return just an view to the data. (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for 201 CREATED)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are replacing whitespaces with underscore in the filename? You can wrap it in quotes to send the actual name.

Comment: @Alexandru Severin: you are right, I would use quotes nowadays. But when I remember right, there was some problems with Whitespaces (not in the http header) but with the browser or fielsystem (maybe just with some strange file system in our testing environment)

Answer (score 81):

If you:

- Don't want to load the whole file into a `byte[]` before sending to the response;
- Want/need to send/download it via `InputStream`;
- Want to have full control of the Mime Type and file name sent;
- Have other `@ControllerAdvice` picking up exceptions for you (or not).

The code below is what you need:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/{stuffId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> downloadStuff(@PathVariable int stuffId)
                                                                      throws IOException {
    String fullPath = stuffService.figureOutFileNameFor(stuffId);
    File file = new File(fullPath);
    long fileLength = file.length(); // this is ok, but see note below

    HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    respHeaders.setContentType("application/pdf");
    respHeaders.setContentLength(fileLength);
    respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "fileNameIwant.pdf");

    return new ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>(
        new FileSystemResource(file), respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK
    );
}
```

**More on `setContentLength()`:** First of all, the [`content-length` header is optional per the HTTP 1.1 RFC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27228549/1850609). Still, if you can provide a value, it is better. To obtain such value, know that `File#length()` should be good enough in the general case, so it is a safe default choice.
In very specific scenarios, though, it [can be slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116574/), in which case you should have it stored previously (e.g. in the DB), not calculated on the fly. Slow scenarios include: if the file is *very* large, specially if it is on a remote system or something more elaborated like that - a database, maybe.

---

#### `InputStreamResource`

If your resource is not a file, e.g. you pick the data up from the DB, you should use [`InputStreamResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html). Example:

```
InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(...);
return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: You don't advise for the use of the FileSystemResource class ?

Comment: Actually, I do believe it is OK to use the `FileSystemResource` there. It is even advisable *if your resource is a file*. In this sample, `FileSystemResource` can be used where `InputStreamResource` is.

Comment: About the file length calculation part: If you are worried, don't be. `File#length()` should be good enough in the general case. I just mentioned it because [it does can be slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116574/), specially if the file is in a remote system or something more elaborated like that - a database, maybe?. But only worry if it becomes a problem (or if you have hard evidence it will become one), not before. The main point is: you are making an effort to stream the file, if you have to preload all of it before, then the streaming ends up making no difference, eh?

Comment: why does the above code not working for me ? It downloads 0 bytes file. I checked and made sure ByteArray & ResourceMessage converters are there. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Why are you worrying about ByteArray & ResourceMessage converters?

Comment: What would be the stream buffer size of `InputStreamResource`?

Comment: Specifying `respHeaders.setContentLength(12345678);` makes the download super slow I guess.

Comment: `setContentLength()` [is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27228343/355438) so it can be omitted

Comment: what do you mean by - If your resource is not a file, then use `new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));` .. what is this file?

Comment: @RamPrakash actually, by "if it is not a file" I mean if you want to send to the user some resource from other source than a file (e.g. you are streaming directly from a database). In this case, you should construct an `InputStreamResource` object. (The example I had left, which I now removed, had an example of constructing an `InputStreamResource` using a file -- which was just an example but you shouldn't do anyway, since if you do want a file you should construct a `FileSystemResource` directly instead).

Answer (score 65):

#### Do

1. Return `ResponseEntity<Resource>` from a handler method
2. Specify `Content-Type`
3. Set `Content-Disposition` if necessary:

   1. filename
   2. type

      1. [`inline`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ContentDisposition.html#inline--) to force preview in a browser
      2. [`attachment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ContentDisposition.html#attachment--) to force a download

#### Example

```java
@Controller
public class DownloadController {
    @GetMapping("/downloadPdf.pdf")
    // 1.
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadPdf() {
        FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("/home/caco3/Downloads/JMC_Tutorial.pdf");
        // 2.
        MediaType mediaType = MediaTypeFactory
                .getMediaType(resource)
                .orElse(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(mediaType);
        // 3
        ContentDisposition disposition = ContentDisposition
                // 3.2
                .inline() // or .attachment()
                // 3.1
                .filename(resource.getFilename())
                .build();
        headers.setContentDisposition(disposition);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

**Return `ResponseEntity<Resource>`**

When you return a [`ResponseEntity<Resource>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html), the [`ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.html) writes file contents

Examples of `Resource` implementations:

- [`ByteArrayResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html) - based in `byte[]`
- [`FileSystemResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html) - for a `File` or a `Path`
- [`UrlResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html) - retrieved from `java.net.URL`
- [`GridFsResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsResource.html) - a blob stored in MongoDB
- [`ClassPathResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) - for files in classpath, for example files from `resources` directory. [My answer to question "Read file from resources folder in Spring Boot"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68913967/6486622) explains how to locate the resource in classpath in details

**Specify `Content-Type` explicitly**:

*Reason: see "[FileSystemResource is returned with content type json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193999/filesystemresource-is-returned-with-content-type-json)" question*

Options:

- Hardcode the header
- Use the [`MediaTypeFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaTypeFactory.html) from Spring. The `MediaTypeFactory` maps `Resource` to `MediaType` using the `/org/springframework/http/mime.types` file
- Use a third party library like [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)

**Set `Content-Disposition` if necessary**:

About [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header:

> The first parameter in the HTTP context is either `inline` (default value, indicating it can be displayed inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or `attachment` (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present).

Use [`ContentDisposition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ContentDisposition.html) in application:

- To *preview* a file in a browser:

  ```java
  ContentDisposition disposition = ContentDisposition
          .inline()
          .filename(resource.getFilename())
          .build();
  ```
- To force a *download*:

  ```java
  ContentDisposition disposition = ContentDisposition
          .attachment()
          .filename(resource.getFilename())
          .build();
  ```

**Use `InputStreamResource` carefully**:

Specify `Content-Length` using the [`HttpHeaders#setContentLength`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#setContentLength-long-) method if:

1. The length is known
2. You use `InputStreamResource`

*Reason: Spring won't write `Content-Length` for `InputStreamResource` because Spring can't determine the length of the resource. Here is a snippet of code from `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`*:

```java
@Override
protected Long getContentLength(Resource resource, @Nullable MediaType contentType) throws IOException {
    // Don't try to determine contentLength on InputStreamResource - cannot be read afterwards...
    // Note: custom InputStreamResource subclasses could provide a pre-calculated content length!
    if (InputStreamResource.class == resource.getClass()) {
        return null;
    }
    long contentLength = resource.contentLength();
    return (contentLength < 0 ? null : contentLength);
}
```

In other cases Spring sets the `Content-Length`:

```bash
~ $ curl -I localhost:8080/downloadPdf.pdf  | grep "Content-Length"
Content-Length: 7554270
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It seems to provide the only clean handling of ContentDisposition and gives clear explanations.

Comment: Definitely the best answer

Comment: Works perfectly, and works with "springdoc-openapi-ui" v1.5.11, swagger-ui. The "Download" link appears as expected with "attachment()" flag.

Answer (score 24):

This code is working fine to download a file automatically from spring controller on clicking a link on jsp.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/downloadLogFile")
public void getLogFile(HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {
        String filePathToBeServed = //complete file name with path;
        File fileToDownload = new File(filePathToBeServed);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
        response.setContentType("application/force-download");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName+".txt"); 
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.debug("Request could not be completed at this moment. Please try again.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: you will face an issue in case of filename contains space,;, etc

Answer (score 20):

Below code worked for me to generate and download a text file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDownloadData() throws Exception {

    String regData = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
    byte[] output = regData.getBytes();

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.set("charset", "utf-8");
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("text/html"));
    responseHeaders.setContentLength(output.length);
    responseHeaders.set("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.txt");

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(output, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What I can quickly think of is, generate the pdf and store it in webapp/downloads/< RANDOM-FILENAME>.pdf from the code and send a forward to this file using HttpServletRequest

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/downloads/<RANDOM-FILENAME>.pdf").forward(request, response);
```

or if you can configure your view resolver something like,

```
  <bean id="pdfViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
              value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="order" value=”2″/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/downloads/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".pdf" />
  </bean>
```

then just return

```
return "RANDOM-FILENAME";
```

Comment: If I need two view resolvers, how can I also return the name of resolver or choose it in controller??

Answer (score 4):

The following solution work for me

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/download")
    public void getLogFile(HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        try {

            String fileName="archivo demo.pdf";
            String filePathToBeServed = "C:\\software\\Tomcat 7.0\\tmpFiles\\";
            File fileToDownload = new File(filePathToBeServed+fileName);

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
            response.setContentType("application/force-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName); 
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception exception){
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

something like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        InputStream is = loader.getResource("classpath:META-INF/resources/Accepted.pdf").getInputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Accepted.pdf");
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}
```

You can display PDF or download it examples [here](http://www.henryxi.com/display-pdf-in-spring-example)

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone. You can do what the accepted answer by Infeligo has suggested but just put this extra bit in the code for a forced download.

```
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm generating some file on demand, so also url has to be generated.

For me works something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
    String path = dataProvider.getFullPath(filename);
    return new FileSystemResource(new File(path));
}
```

Very important is mime type in `produces` and also that, that name of the file is a part of the link so you has to use `@PathVariable`.

HTML code looks like that:

```
<a th:href="@{|/dbreport/files/${file_name}|}">Download</a>
```

Where `${file_name}` is generated by Thymeleaf in controller and is i.e.: result_20200225.csv, so that whole url behing link is: `example.com/aplication/dbreport/files/result_20200225.csv`.

After clicking on link browser asks me what to do with file - save or open.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add this to download any file

```
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment;filename="+"file.txt");
```

all code:

```
@Controller
public class FileController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method =RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getFile(HttpServletResponse response) {

    final File file = new File("file.txt");
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment;filename="+"file.txt");
    return new FileSystemResource(file);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a useful answer.

[Is it ok to export data as pdf format in frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034234/is-it-ok-to-export-data-as-pdf-format-in-frontend/)

Extending to this, adding content-disposition as an attachment(default) will download the file. If you want to view it, you need to set it to inline.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way to do it with SpringBoot:

```
import org.springframework.http.ContentDisposition;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;    

@GetMapping("/file/{fileName}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
        // Create Headers for "forcing download"
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
        // Headers for giving a custom name to the file and also the file extension, in this example .zip
        httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            ContentDisposition.attachment().filename(String.format("%s.%s", fileName, "zip")).build().toString());
        // Get the bytes from your service (for example an aws bucket)
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(httpHeaders).body(service.getFile(fileName));
    }
```

the above code works, but its only for showing you how simple and easy it can be, but you should first check if the file exists before doing anything, then create the headers in another method and finally return (for clean code).