# Return a file from Controller in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring. I have a controller with a RequestMapping for several GET parameters. They return a String .
But one method needs to return a file in the "/res/" folder. How do I do that?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value = "/getfile")
public @ResponseBody 
String getReviewedFile(@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName)
{
    return //the File Content or better the file itself
}
```

Thanks

Comment: See answer in here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to @JAR.JAR.beans. Here is the link: [Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody 
public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName) {
    return new FileSystemResource(myService.getFileFor(fileName)); 
}
```

Comment: In addition to this, you can also return a file with dynamically generated content. You will need to return byte[] in ResponseEntity with appropriate headers to do that. Here is an example: https://allaboutspringframework.com/java-spring-download-file-from-controller/

Answer (score 8):

May be this will help

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value = "/getfile")
public @ResponseBody 
void getReviewedFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName)
{
    //do other stuff
    byte[] file = //get your file from the location and convert it to bytes
    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType("image/png"); //or whatever file type you want to send. 
    try {
        response.getOutputStream().write(image);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, though [Jatin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13120095/2946008) is way cooler :

```
//Created inside the "scope" of @ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${files.dir}")
    private String filesDir;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/files/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:" + filesDir);
    }
}
```

Lifted from:

- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources
- https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources

Comment: OK, what if I want `https://my-site.com/prefix/to/remove/file.png` to return `/images/file.png`? What should I write in `addResourceHandler` to specify that `/prefix/to/remove` parth must be removed? So far I see that Spring tries to find `/images/prefix/to/remove/file.png` instead of `/images/file.png`.

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm for me:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/image/{imageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable String imageId) {
        RandomAccessFile f = null;
        try {
            f = new RandomAccessFile(configs.getImagePath(imageId), "r");
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            f.readFully(b);
            f.close();
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
            return  new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(b, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on local Windows machine this could be useful for you:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getImage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource getUserFile(HttpServletResponse response){

        final File file = new File("D:\\image\\img1.jpg");

        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");


        return new FileSystemResource(file);
    }
```

for testing your code you can use **Postman** "Use **Send And Download** not just **send**"

**Another Approach** to return **byte**:

```
@GetMapping("/getAppImg")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getImage() throws IOException {

        File serveFile = new File("image_path\\img.jpg");

        return Files.readAllBytes(serveFile.toPath());
    }
```