# File download using RESTful gives HTTP 406 Not Applicable Error

Tags: java, spring, rest, extjs, download

I'm trying to download an Excel file using RESTful call. I thought it should be pretty simple, but I keep getting HTTP 406 Not Applicable Eror. This is what my controller method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gettemplate", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
@ResponseBody
public Response getExcelTemplate() throws Exception {
    File templateFile = new File("TestFile.xlsx");
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(templateFile,"application/vnd.ms-excel");
    builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + templateFile.getName() + "\"" );
    return builder.build();
}
```

I've tried setting request header to accept `application/vnd.ms-excel`, I've also tried using `application/octet-stream` instead of `vnd.ms-excel`. I get an HTML response back with 406 error message in either case. Here's what my Ajax test call looks like:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'myservice/gettemplate',
    //dataType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.ms-excel, text/plain, */*'
        //'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    },
    success: function (response, options) {
        alert(1);
    },
    failure: function (response, options) {
        alert(2);
    }
});
```

I've commented out the lines that I've tried and removed as it didn't help. This could be a very simple config change, but I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: The content type is being declared twice, once in the `produces` value in the @RequestMapping annotation and another one on the ResponseBuilder. Try removing one of them.

Comment: @ESala Removing one doesn't help. Tried changing to `ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(templateFile);` still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat based on ESala's answer I tried a few things. Finally got it working by setting header and content type to `HttpServletResponse`. Here's the code that worked for me. This works in both IE and Firefox flawlessly with just a simple anchor tag, without even an ajax call. Hope it helps someone else.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/gettemplate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getExcelTemplate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TestFile.xlsx");

    InputStream fis = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("templates/TestFile.xlsx");
    int x = fis.available();
    byte byteArray[] = new byte[x];
    logger.info(" File size :"+byteArray.length);
    fis.read(byteArray);

    response.getOutputStream().write(byteArray);
    response.flushBuffer();
    fis.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you annotate a request mapping return type with `@ResponseBody`, Spring will attempt to convert the object into the response using an `HttpMessageConverter`, as it says on the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) page:

> **@ResponseBody** As with @RequestBody, Spring converts the returned object to a
>   response body by using an HttpMessageConverter.

You can see the list of available converters here: [Message converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-string-converter)

It looks like the `application/vnd.ms-excel` you specify is not supported by any of the converters. Maybe that is why you get a 406.

> **406 Not Acceptable**
>   The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent
>   in the request.

The solution in your case is to remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation and **handle the file download in another way**.

See here for examples on how to download a file from a Spring controller:

[Downloading a file from Spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

[Returning a file from a controller in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119759/return-a-file-from-controller-in-spring)

Comment: I have the same problem with `application/octet-stream` as well, it is there on the list of Message Converters you mentioned.