# Stream directly to response output stream in handler method of Spring MVC 3.1 controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, httpresponse

I have a controller method that handles ajax calls and returns JSON. I am using the JSON library from json.org to create the JSON.

I could do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getJson()
{
    JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject();

    // Populate JSON

    return rootJson.toString();
}
```

But it is inefficient to put together the JSON string, only to have Spring write it to the response's output stream.

Instead, I can write it directly to the response output stream like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getJson(HttpServletResponse response)
{
    JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject();

    // Populate JSON

    rootJson.write(response.getWriter());
}
```

But it seems like there would be a better way to do this than having to resort to passing the `HttpServletResponse` into the handler method.

Is there another class or interface that can be returned from the handler method that I can use, along with the `@ResponseBody` annotation?

Comment: What is wrong with "passing the HttpServletResponse into the handler method"?

Comment: @arahant - That's a fair question. I guess I'm under the impression that, although it's possible, it's not the correct way of doing things. There's an answer by @Ralph in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers) that's says it makes testing harder. Before I write a lot of handler methods that do this, I wanted to find out if there's another way. So far it looks like I would have to write a custom `HttpMessageConverter`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can have the Output Stream or the Writer as an parameter of your controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getJson(Writer responseWriter) {
    JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject();
    rootJson.write(responseWriter);
}
```

@see [Spring Reference Documentation 3.1 Chapter 16.3.3.1 Supported method argument types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

p.s. I feel that using `OutputStream` or `Writer` as an parameter is still much more easier to use in tests than a `HttpServletResponse` - and thanks for paying attention to [what I have written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13120104/280244) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Passing an `OutputStream` or a `Writer` is preferable to passing the `HttpServletResponse`.

Answer (score 4):

In the end, I wrote an `HttpMessageConverter` for this. With it, I can do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject getJson()
    throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject();

    // Populate JSON

    return rootJson;
}
```

Here is my `HttpMessageConverter` class:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;

public class JsonObjectHttpMessageConverter
    extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<JSONObject>
{
    private static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    public JsonObjectHttpMessageConverter()
    {
        super(new MediaType("application", "json"), new MediaType("text", "javascript"));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        return JSONObject.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject readInternal(Class<? extends JSONObject> clazz,
                                      HttpInputMessage            inputMessage)
        throws IOException,
               HttpMessageNotReadableException
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(JSONObject        jsonObject,
                                 HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException,
               HttpMessageNotWritableException
    {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody(),
                                                                    getContentTypeCharset(outputMessage)));

        try
        {
            jsonObject.write(writer);
            writer.flush();
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private Charset getContentTypeCharset(HttpMessage message)
    {
        MediaType contentType = message.getHeaders().getContentType();

        Charset charset = (contentType != null) ? contentType.getCharSet() : null;

        return (charset != null) ? charset : DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    }
}
```

The `HttpMessageConverter` must be registered with Spring. This can be done in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file like this:

```
<beans ...>

    ...    

    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" validator="validator">
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            ...
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>*/*</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="false" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="com.example.JsonObjectHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    ...

</beans>
```

As you can see, I have other `HttpMessageConverter` objects registered too. The order does matter.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply your own post with an updated answer, which is IMHO the best one.

Comment: @SteveMARION - You're welcome. It was looking like I was the only one who would bother doing this. I figured this answer would not get as many votes as the accepted answer, but I thought it would be closer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you use the OutputStream or Writer it requires you to write the headers yourself.

One workaround is to use InputStreamResource/ResourceHttpMessageConverter