# Convert a file Jrxml to FileOutputStream and show it in an HTML page

Tags: java, spring, pdf, jasper-reports, outputstream

I have a file jrxml (create using Jasper Report) and I want show it in an HTML page without using for example pdf file. I want do this conversion by server side (spring).

I call the java method from the page HTML using:

```
<FORM NAME="formTicket" ACTION='http://localhost:8080/movies/ticket' METHOD="GET">
```

and in java I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/movies/ticket", method = RequestMethod.GET)//stampa ticket
public Document add(@RequestParam(value="id")int id, int numb) {//numb=numeroBigliettiDaStampare,Id=specificoMovie
    String xmlFile = serv.getPDF(id, numb);
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try{
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFile)));
        return doc;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and the getPDF method, with JasperReports:

```
public String getPDF(int id, int number){
    String fileJrxml = "/home/salvador/workspace/serverMovies/src/main/webapp/resources/Jasper/ticket.jrxml";
    File jasperFileSource = new File(fileJrxml);
    //Log.debug("Crando il PDF");
      try
      {
          ArrayList<Movie> film=new ArrayList<Movie>();
         // film.add(moviedao.getMovie(id));
          Movie f; 
          int posto=1;
          int fila=1;
          for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
              f = new Movie(moviedao.getMovie(id).getTitle(),moviedao.getMovie(id).getActor(),moviedao.getMovie(id).getGenre(),moviedao.getMovie(id).getYear(),moviedao.getMovie(id).getLanguage());
              f.setDurata("80m");
              posto = posto +1;
              fila = fila +1;
              f.setPosto(posto+"");
              f.setFila(fila+"");
              f.setPrezzo("8.50");
              film.add(f);
          }


        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jasperFileSource);

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(film);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, jrDataSource);

        String xmlStr = JasperExportManager.exportReportToXml(jasperPrint);

        //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "/home/salvador/workspace/serverMovies/src/main/webapp/resources/ticket.pdf");

        //Log.debug("PDF creato");
        //System.out.println("Pdf file successfully generated.");

        return xmlStr;

      }//try
      catch (JRException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Error during the generation of PDF file.\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
      } //catch
      return "errore";
}//getPDF
```

I find the solution for this problem, this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/movies/ticket", method = RequestMethod.GET)//stampa ticket
public void getTicket(@RequestParam(value="id")int id, int numb, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {//numb=numeroBigliettiDaStampare,Id=specificoMovie
    byte[] xmlFile = serv.getPDF(id, numb);
    serv.streamReport(response, xmlFile, "report.pdf");
}//add
```

that call two methods, the first that create from JasperReport a byteStream:

```
public byte[] getPDF(int id, int number){
    String fileJrxml = "/home/salvador/workspace/serverMovies/src/main/webapp/resources/Jasper/ticket.jrxml";
    File jasperFileSource = new File(fileJrxml);
    //Log.debug("Crando il PDF");
      try
      {
          ArrayList<Movie> film=new ArrayList<Movie>();
         // film.add(moviedao.getMovie(id));
          Movie f; 
          int posto=1;
          int fila=1;
          for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
              f = new Movie(moviedao.getMovie(id).getTitle(),moviedao.getMovie(id).getActor(),moviedao.getMovie(id).getGenre(),moviedao.getMovie(id).getYear(),moviedao.getMovie(id).getLanguage());
              f.setDurata("80m");
              posto = posto +1;
              fila = fila +1;
              f.setPosto(posto+"");
              f.setFila(fila+"");
              f.setPrezzo("8.50");
              film.add(f);
          }//for i


        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jasperFileSource);

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(film);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, jrDataSource);

        byte[] data= JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

        return data;

      }//try
      catch (JRException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Error during the generation of PDF file.\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
      } //catch
      return null;
}//getPDF
```

and the second where I use the stream to show my JasperReport in the browser:

```
public void streamReport(HttpServletResponse response, byte[] data, String name) throws IOException
{
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    response.setContentLength(data.length);
    response.getOutputStream().write(data);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
}// streamReport
```

Comment: You like pdf output correct?, what do you like to send to browser?

Comment: i want to show my jasper report in the browser

Comment: What do you mean with jasper report, you want to show the exported result (pdf) of your jasper report in the browser, correct?...(I see getPDF)

Comment: yes, sorry, now i explain better. Before i create a file pdf from my jasper report and then i charge this file on the browser. Now i want do the same thing, but i want do this without create a file, and see my result on the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The easy way:**

```xml
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
```

**The most configurable:**

```xml
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();             
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));

SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
//configuration.setConfigurations....;
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

For how to stream directly to browser in Spring context see

[Stream directly to response output stream in handler method of Spring MVC 3.1 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283347/stream-directly-to-response-output-stream-in-handler-method-of-spring-mvc-3-1-co)

The `writer` is what you pass as `outputStream`

Don't forget to add the header in your response

`"Content-disposition", "filename=report.pdf"` , display in page

`"Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf"`, download it

**EDIT**: I seen that you answered by yourself in question, to improve your code consider that you do not need to compile jrxml everytime.

```xml
@RequestMapping(value = "/movies/ticket", method = RequestMethod.GET)//stampa ticket
public void getTicket(@RequestParam(value="id")int id, int numb, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    //Use the complied file,you do not need to compile the jrxml everytime
    //Furthermore since its in src (I would have use class loader)
    String fileJasper = "/home/salvador/workspace/serverMovies/src/main/webapp/resources/Jasper/ticket.jasper";
    JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(fileJasper);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, getDataSource(id));
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response);
}
```

Comment: thank you Petter,I have already tried only the easy way, now i'll try the most configurable but how can I redirect the output stream to the browser page opened?

Comment: You are using spring?, maybe this can help to see how you get the outputsteam / writer in your method... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283347/stream-directly-to-response-output-stream-in-handler-method-of-spring-mvc-3-1-co

Comment: The above method's should work both, the difference is that you can configure your output in the second... in outputStream you need to pass the HttpServletResponse's writer (the outstream of the servlet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, destFileName) to create HTML

Comment: yes, but i won't create a file to charge the html page, it's possible in other ways, for example with an outputStream?

Comment: Just create empty Html file in you project and then pass it's location as "destFileName". After that you can redirect your user to that Html page or read it and put in outputstream if want.