# Java - processing large files

Tags: java, arrays, file, spring-mvc

I'm working on a spring mvc application. at this time i need to have action for file downloading. due to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800565/spring-mvc-large-files-for-download-outofmemoryexception) my controller's action now is like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/file/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void getFile(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException {

    //fetch file record from database
    Files file = orchService.fileFind(id);

    //directory of the file is based on file ID(this is not important in this question)
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFileDirectory);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename " + file.getId() + "."+file.getExtension()+"\"");
    int read=0;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[];

    //remaining of code
}
```

my problem is on the `bytes` declaration. `file` has a `long getSize()` method that return the size of the files. but i can't use `byte[] bytes = new byte[file.getSize()];`, because the array size must be an integer value. how can i solve this problem?

I don't want to copy whole file into memory.

Comment: If you really want to copy the whole file into memory (which I doubt), you can use `byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);`

Comment: i don't want to copy whole file into memory. because of OutOfMemory exception in large files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) and just copy streams (file stream to response stream)

```
copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
```

Copies bytes from an InputStream to an OutputStream.

```
copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output, int bufferSize)
```

Copies bytes from an InputStream to an OutputStream using an internal buffer of the given size.

Comment: I see documentation and IOUtils has static "copy" method with 3 parameter, but netbeans gives me error: "no suitable method...". netbeans doesn't suggest copy method with 3 parameter!!! my netbeans version is 8.0

Comment: Check the apache commons version you use in the project.

Comment: I have "commons-io-2.4.jar" in my project dependencies.

Comment: Check whether the version has the method. If not upgrade to the version where the method is supported

Answer (score 1):

Read your data in a loop with a buffer of bytes. Reading to large byte arrays could be a performance issue.

If you need to save the data use a file or stream.

[Reading a binary input stream into a single byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250229/reading-a-binary-file-into-a-single-byte-array-in-java)