# How to make download function in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, controller, download

I have made an upload function and it runs well. It stores the uploaded file to "C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/Upload/"
But, now I want to make this app be able to download the file.

I have been searching in google but I cannot find.

This is the code for the model:

```
public class UploadForm {

private String name = null;
private CommonsMultipartFile file = null;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public CommonsMultipartFile getFile() {
    return file;
}
public void setFile(CommonsMultipartFile file) {
    this.file = file;
    this.name = file.getOriginalFilename();
}
```

}

This is the controller:

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping(value="/FileUploadForm.htm")
public class UploadFormController implements HandlerExceptionResolver{

```
private String filePath = "C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/Upload/";

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(ModelMap model){
    UploadForm form = new UploadForm();
    model.addAttribute("FORM", form);
    return "FileUploadForm";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute(value="FORM") UploadForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] file) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(filePath);

        if(file != null && file.length > 0) {
            for(CommonsMultipartFile aFiles : file) {
                if(!aFiles.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                    aFiles.transferTo(new File(filePath + aFiles.getOriginalFilename()));
                }
            }
            return "success";
        }else{
            return "FileUploadForm";
        }   
}


@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception exception) {
    Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    if (exception instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException)
    {
        model.put("errors", "File size should be less then "+((MaxUploadSizeExceededException)exception).getMaxUploadSize()+" byte.");
    } else
    {
        model.put("errors", "Unexpected error: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
    model.put("FORM", new UploadForm());
    return new ModelAndView("/FileUploadForm", (Map) model);

}
```

}

This is the FileUploadForm.jsp page:

```
        <form:form commandName="FORM" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan="2" style="color: red;"><form:errors path="*" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
            ${errors}
        </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Choose File:</td>
            <td><form:input type="file" name="file" path="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Upload File" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
```

Last, this is the Success.jsp page:

```
    <h3 style="color: green;">File has been uploaded successfully.</h3> <br>
File Name : ${FORM.name}.
</br><a href="...">Download this file here</a>
```

Any ideas or solutions is greatly appreciated and welcomed.

Best Regards,
Yunus

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers