# Spring: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, spring, outputstream, illegalstateexception

I know that there are many other posts dealing with the very same error, but all of them are either about JSP / GSP pages or for any other reason not very helpful in my case. I'm using Spring MVC with Thymeleaf. The following function is for downloading a file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/download/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getFile(HttpServletResponse response)
{

    ServletOutputStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        stream = response.getOutputStream();

        MultipartFile f = test.getFile();

        InputStream is = f.getInputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, stream);
        response.flushBuffer();

        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

    } catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return "test";

}
```

It does actually work, so it's not too much of a problem, but in the console, I'm always getting the following error:

```
2014-01-10T09:28:09.053+0100  SEVERE  Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception  [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:638)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:214)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.getWriter(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:125)
at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
[...]
```

As far as I see, `getOutputStream()` is only called once. Also, the whole function is surrounded with a `try-catch`-block. So I'd like to know, where does this error come from?

Comment: `f = test.getFile()` What is `test`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you return 'test', you are instructing your controller to send you to some view... after using the response outputStream to return a binary file.  Here is an idea of how you should manage this:

[Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

Answer (score 4):

I just experienced this problem.

The problem was caused by my controller method attempting return type of **String (view name)** when it exits. When the method would exit, a second response stream would be initiated.

Changing the controller method return type to **void** resolved the problem.

I hope this helps if anyone else experiences this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send `String` then you could change

```
return "test";
```

to

```
return null;
```