# how to read downloaded pdf file in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pdf

I am new in spring mvc . so my question is how to read downloaded pdf file .my jsp page have pdf download link. and pdf is downloading properly when i click on that link but when i opened it . it shows blank file. so can anybody tell me that how to read pdf file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadnotepadfile(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    String filename = "Application-Form-2014";
    try {
        String path = "f:\\";
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        File f = new File(path + "//" + filename);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(new Long(f.length()).intValue());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=\""+filename+"\"");


        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
       int a = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        }
```

please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers check this

Comment: i have tried it but not working . and file is downloading but not reading pdf data