# download uploaded file using spring mvc abstractions (avoid using raw HttpServletResponse)

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, io, download

I am trying to add file uploading and downloading in my web application.

I am used to **don't use** raw `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` when I use spring mvc. But now I have following controller to download files.

```
public ModelAndView download(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    int id = ServletRequestUtils.getRequiredIntParameter(request, "id");

    Files file = this.filesService.find(id);

    response.setContentType(file.getType());
    response.setContentLength(file.getFile().length);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() +"\"");

    FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getFile(), response.getOutputStream());

    return null;

}
```

As you can see I use `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` here.

I want to find way to avoid using of these classes. Is it possible?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Downloading a file from spring controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers). The second solution (rather than the accepted one) is the one that you want.

Comment: Why don't you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

The `id` parameter that you are getting from `request` can be substituted with the use of `@RequestParam` or `@PathVariable`. See bellow for an example of `@RequestParam`

```
public ModelAndView download(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
   // Now you can use the variable id as Spring MVC has extracted it from the HttpServletRequest 
   Files file = this.filesService.find(id); // Continue from here...
}
```

And now the response part

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download(@RequestParam("id") int id) throws IOException
{   
    // Use of http headers....
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

    InputStream is // Get your file contents read into this input stream
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(is), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: You are loading the whole file into memory. This solution will not scale