# What are the consequences of not including a content-length header in a server response?

Tags: http, http-headers, httpresponse, content-length

The [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) says the `content-length` header is optional ("..Applications SHOULD use this field...").

From what I can gather if its not included then the client will not know how much data to expect, therefore will not be able to show a determinate progress bar when downloading the body (i.e. the top bar instead of the bottom).

[image: progress]

Are there any other side effects or bugs that arise from omitting this header?

Answer (score 17):

I think your implicit question is *"How does a client detect the end of an HTTP message?"*. See [RFC 7230 - HTTP/1.1 Message Syntax and Routing - Message Body Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3):

> The length of a message body is determined by one of the following
> (in order of precedence):

> 1. Any response to a HEAD request and any response with a 1xx
>    (Informational), 204 (No Content), or 304 (Not Modified) status
>    code is always terminated by the first empty line after the
>    header fields, regardless of the header fields present in the
>    message, and thus cannot contain a message body.

> 2. Any 2xx (Successful) response to a CONNECT request implies that
>    the connection will become a tunnel immediately after the empty
>    line that concludes the header fields.  A client MUST ignore any
>    Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header fields received in
>    such a message.

> 3. If a Transfer-Encoding header field is present and the chunked
>    transfer coding (Section 4.1) is the final encoding, the message
>    body length is determined by reading and decoding the chunked
>    data until the transfer coding indicates the data is complete.

> ```
>   If a Transfer-Encoding header field is present in a response and
> ```

```
   the chunked transfer coding is not the final encoding, the
   message body length is determined by reading the connection until
   it is closed by the server.  If a Transfer-Encoding header field
   is present in a request and the chunked transfer coding is not
   the final encoding, the message body length cannot be determined
   reliably; the server MUST respond with the 400 (Bad Request)
   status code and then close the connection.
```

> ```
>   If a message is received with both a Transfer-Encoding and a
> ```

```
   Content-Length header field, the Transfer-Encoding overrides the
   Content-Length.  Such a message might indicate an attempt to
   perform request smuggling (Section 9.5) or response splitting
   (Section 9.4) and ought to be handled as an error.  A sender MUST
   remove the received Content-Length field prior to forwarding such
   a message downstream.
```

> 4. If a message is received without Transfer-Encoding and with
>    either multiple Content-Length header fields having differing
>    field-values or a single Content-Length header field having an
>    invalid value, then the message framing is invalid and the
>    recipient MUST treat it as an unrecoverable error.  If this is a
>    request message, the server MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request)
>    status code and then close the connection.  If this is a response
>    message received by a proxy, the proxy MUST close the connection
>    to the server, discard the received response, and send a 502 (Bad
>    Gateway) response to the client.  If this is a response message
>    received by a user agent, the user agent MUST close the
>    connection to the server and discard the received response.

> 5. If a valid Content-Length header field is present without
>    Transfer-Encoding, its decimal value defines the expected message
>    body length in octets.  If the sender closes the connection or
>    the recipient times out before the indicated number of octets are
>    received, the recipient MUST consider the message to be
>    incomplete and close the connection.

> 6. If this is a request message and none of the above are true, then
>    the message body length is zero (no message body is present).

> 7. Otherwise, this is a response message without a declared message
>    body length, so the message body length is determined by the
>    number of octets received prior to the server closing the
>    connection.

When the server omits the content-length header, it has to use one of the other mechanisms to indicate the end of the message.

So to answer your question: scenarios 3 (chunking) and 7 (reading until the server closes the connection) are the ones where the client doesn't know the length on beforehand.