# Render pdf file in a browser

Tags: php

I am trying to display pdf in broswer window and getting some text as a response.Please tell me where I am doing the mistake.Here's my code:

```
$filepath = 'ssh2.sftp://<ftpuser>:<ftp password>@<ftphost>/scratch/user1/opt/portal/7.5/custom/apps/cus_transfer_invoice/BA10000892/B1-13370/Invoice_BA10000892_B1-13370_189.pdf';

header('Content-type: application/pdf');

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($filepath);
```

I am getting the output as something like this :

> JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMiAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNTIvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0KeJwr5HIK4TI2UzA3M9Azs1AISeFyDeEK5CpUMFQwAEIImZyroB+RZqjgkq8QyAUACHQKjQplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZS9QYWdlL01lZGlhQm94WzAgMCA2MTIgNzk2LjY4XS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Qcm9jU2V0IFsvUERGIC9UZXh0IC9JbWFnZUIgL0ltYWdlQyAvSW1hZ2VJXS9YT2JqZWN0PDwvWGYxIDEgMCBSPj4+Pi9Db250ZW50cyAyIDAgUi9QYXJlbnQgMyAwIFI+PgplbmRvYmoKNiAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNTIvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0KeJwr5HIK4TI2UzA3M9Azs1AISeFyDeEK5CpUMFQwAEIImZyroB+RZqTgkq8QyAUACHsKjgplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjcgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZS9QYWdlL01lZGlhQm94WzAgMCA2MTIgNzk2LjY4XS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Qcm9jU2V0IFsvUERGIC9UZXh0IC9JbWFnZUIgL0ltYWdlQyAvSW1hZ2VJXS9YT2JqZWN0PDwvWGYyIDUgMCBSPj4+Pi9Db250ZW50cyA2IDAgUi9QYXJlbnQgMyAwIFI+PgplbmRvYmoKOSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNDkvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0KeJwr5HIK4TI2UzA3NVMISeFyDeEK5CpUMFQwAEIImZyroB+RZqzgkq8QyAUA60cJ+AplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjEwIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUvUGFnZS9NZWRpYUJveFswIDAg"

Comment: Im not particularly sure about this but what i did in my previous project was to only redirect the in a blank tab the file path location

Comment: @Miggy: Using php?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Content-Length header. That's almost certainly your problem. See eg [Sending correct file size with PHP download script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972642/sending-correct-file-size-with-php-download-script/39652287)
If it works without that header, you can either try to work out exactly why the header is wrong, or just send no content-length (which basically will work OK)

See [What are the consequences of not including a content-length header in a server response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228343/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-including-a-content-length-header-in-a-server-r) for more on what happens if you just go without a Content-Length header.