# FileSystemResource is returned with content type json

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the following spring mvc method that returns a file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public FileSystemResource getFiles(@PathVariable String fileName){

    String path="/home/marios/Desktop/";

    return new FileSystemResource(path+fileName);

}
```

I expect a ResourceHttpMessageConverter to create the appropriate response with an octet-stream type according to its documentation:

> If JAF is not available, application/octet-stream is used.

However although I correctly get the file without a problem, the result has **Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8**

Can you tell me why this happens?

(I use spring version 4.1.4. I have not set explicitly any message converters and I know that spring loads by default among others the ResourceHttpMessageConverter and also the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter because I have jackson 2 in my classpath due to the fact that I have other mvc methods that return json.

Also if I use `HttpEntity<FileSystemResource>` and set manually the content type, or specify it with `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` it works fine.

Note also that in my request I do not specify any accept content types, and prefer not to rely on my clients to do that)

Comment: I think you've answered your own question, it sounds like the jackson converter is taking precedence over the resource converter.

Comment: The JAF is always available except if you use a very old Java version ;)

Comment: But the result is written successfully by ResourceHttpMessageConverter because it is a file , why is the content type taken from MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182523/spring-rest-web-service-return-file-as-resource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up debugging the whole thing, and I found that `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter` has a `canWrite` implementation that returns true in case of the `FileSystemResource` because it just checks if class is serializable, and the set media type which is null since I do not specify any which in that case is supposed to be supported by it.

As a result it ends up putting the json content types in a list of producible media types. Of course `ResourceHttpMessageConverter.canWrite` implementation also naturally returns true, but the `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` does not return any producible media types.

When the time to write the actual response comes, from the `write` method implementation, the write of the `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` runs first due to the fact that the `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` is first in the list of the available converters (if `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` was first, it would try to call `write` since its `canWrite` returns true and throw exception), and since there was already a producible content type set, it does not default to running the `ResourceHttpMessageConverter.getDefaultContentType` that would set the correct content type.

If I remove json converter all would work fine, but unfortunately none of my json methods would work. Therefore specifying the content type is the only way to get rid of the returned json content type

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for a piece of code:

You should wrap your `FileSystemResource` into a `ResponseEntity<>`
Then determine your image's content type and append it to `ResponseEntity` as a header.

Here is an example:

```java
@GetMapping("/image")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> getImage() throws IOException {

    File file = /* load your image file from anywhere */;
    if (!file.exists()) {
        //TODO: throw 404
    }

    FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(file);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(/* determine your image's media type or just set it as a constant using MediaType.<value> */);
    headers.setContentLength(resource.contentLength());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```