# PDF download in new window in java

Tags: java, json, pdf

My requirement for PDF download is:

1. When user click on  "Download" link, front-end will *POST* a JSON data to the back-end.
2. Back-end will process the JSON, generating a PDF file from it's parameters.
3. In response I (back-end) need to send a download link and unique document id.
4. Frond-end will open that link *(GET)* in new window which will hit the back-end and download will start.

How should I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Do you have the PDF byte array? Are you using a plain java servlet to map the download URL? How the json will be sent from the client? Is it a POST? a GET? Please, elaborate.

Comment: I am using spring. JSON data will come in POST request. After that I am creating JASPER Report using this data.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Spring you create a Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/report")
public class ReportController {

    @Autowired
    ReportFileStore reportFileStore;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/download/{uniqueId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(@PathVariable("uniqueId") String uniqueId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        //Find the generated PDF from somewhere, might be a disk, or RAM
        byte[] pdf = getFromStore(uniqueId);

        writeToResponse(pdf,response);
        deleteFileFromStore(uniqueId);
    }

    private byte[] getFromStore(String uniqueId){
        return reportFileStore.getFile(uniqueId);
    }
}
```

The method `writeToResponse` is a standard servlet download code, you can see a example [here](http://www.andreagirardi.it/blog/how-to-download-pdf-file-from-url-on-mvc-controller/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers).

About the `getFromStore`, that is a simple method get the byte[] of the PDF generated from Jasper, when you generate you can have put method that stores the byte[] with the uniqueId.

I'd use a interface like this

```
public interface ReportFileStore {
     void storeFile(String uniqueId,byte[] content);
     byte[] getFile(String uniqueId);
     InputStream getFile(String uniqueId);
     void deleteFile(String uniqueId);
}
```

And implement it using a VFS mapped on a RAM or Disk.

---

Of course, on your PDF generation, you need to generate a unique ID for it, you can try using [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). Use this UUID with the `ReportFileStore` to save the PDF file. It's unclear if the "need to return a download link and a unique id" can be done just returning the uniqueId, then hardcoding the download location on the front-end. If not, return a JSON mapping it.

Comment: Could you also share sample code for getFromStore(uniqueId)

Comment: I added a sample implementation on a controller.

Comment: That `getFromStore()` would be `reportFileStore.getFile()`, i think... Also `deleteFileFromStore()` would be `reportFileStore.deletFile()`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto, yes, they have the same signature, the code above is just pseudo-code on how to create a file download endpoint. The idea is to generate the PDF, store at the `interface ReportFileStore`  and then use it stream the file contents at the Controller