# How to return a file in spring boot controller along with response message?

Tags: file, spring-boot, controller

I need to return a **PDF document** from a Spring Boot `@Controller` along with the **password** required to open it. 
I get the filename as **PathParam** `user/document/{filename}`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing specific to spring-boot for that, it's handled with a good old Spring MVC's.

[This other answer from @Infeligo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5673356/641627) explains it perflectly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/document/{filename}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(
    @PathParam("filename") String fileName, 
    HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
      // get your file as InputStream
      InputStream is = ...;
      // copy it to response's OutputStream
      org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
      response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '{}'", fileName, ex);
      throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}
```

You could set the password in a header field (how much does it need to be secure?):

```
response.addHeader("pdf_password", "thisIsThePassword");
```