# Download a file from a browser in a Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, download, freemarker

I have a requirement to download a csv file from a Spring MVC application. I have the data which I need to include in the file. I need to create a file on the fly in the browser session and download it to the user system. I tried doing the solution as mentioned here: [Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

I was unable to produce the csv and it is looking for a file on the server.

What I have done so far:

Client Side Call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"${ctx}/emp/getAttendance?empId=" + emp +"&fileName=" + file,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result_loading').hide();
        }
    });
```

Server Side:

```
    String path = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
    File file = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
    file.createNewFile();
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
    resp.setHeader("content-disposition;","attachment;filename=\"download.pdf\"");
    OutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
```

I need the Ajax call to download the file. I don't see even an empty file downloaded.

Can someone help me with this on where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Look at the [third answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5673375/5221149) of the question you linked.

Comment: Mine is an Ajax call. I don't think that approach works.

Comment: What does that have to do with how the server side code works?

Comment: I have added the code which I wrote.

Comment: Why do you tell jQuery that you expect `json` response, when you actually send PDF response?

Comment: Modified and added the new code.

Comment: What is the purpose of the Ajax call when you ignore the `data` returned to the `success` function?

Comment: @Andreas Do you have a solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136779/discussion-between-sri-and-andreas).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FileSystemResource` class from the spring framework
the class exists in the location

```
org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
```

Write your data onto a file (on the physical server) by creating a csv file using the `java.io.File` Class and then pass the value of the file object to the constructor

```
FileSystemResource(File file)
```

and return this to the browser, the browser will automatically open up a download window once the url is loaded.

Delete the file once the file system resource is initialized, and you would be as good as you never created the file.