# Downloading PPT File Using Spring MVC and Apache POI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I am trying to return a PowerPoint file asynchronously to the client from a Spring MVC @RequestMapping method using Apache POI's [HSFL](https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html). However I can't get the file to download

Here's my code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPPT", produces = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
public @ResponseBody byte[] downloadPPT(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytes = null;
    HSLFSlideShow ppt = new HSLFSlideShow();

    // add first slide
    HSLFSlide s1 = ppt.createSlide();

    // add second slide
    HSLFSlide s2 = ppt.createSlide();

    // save changes in a file
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("slideshow.ppt");

    ppt.write(outputStream);
    out.close();
    bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

    return bytes;

}
```

My response seems to be a byte-version of the ppt file I created, however the user doesn't get prompted to download the file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to return anything.
just try

OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

ppt.write(os);

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"slideshow.ppt\"");

and inside finally

os.flush();

os.close();

Try submitting a form from UI, you will get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Tasmine, hitting my Controller method directly in Internet Explorer is the only method that forces the download. Otherwise the download never initiates. Any thoughts on this?