# Spring boot download file just being shown in browser, not actually downloading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-io

I have followed this example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName) {
    return new FileSystemResource(myService.getFileFor(fileName)); 
}
```

from this thread: [Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

This works fine, but instead of downloading the file, the browser displays it.

In the comments someone mentions to add:

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
```

in order to force the browser to download the file. However this still doesn't work for me. Anyone have any idea how to force the download?

Comment: You haven't read the link you have shared you need to write to the response output stream, you also need to remove @ResponseBody

Comment: @EssexBoy I am using the second example from that link, not the first. I haven't missed anything, right?

Comment: You need to use the accepted answer that will work fine

Comment: @EssexBoy tried that as well, same problem.