# Download file, after generating it based on user input

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, file, web

I have a button on my web app which when clicked generates a text file based on user inputs.
For this i use ajax that send parameters to spring backend. This works. What I want is on the same button when clicked generated file to be downloaded on user computer.

Can this be done without storing the file on server and generating link ?

Comment: can [this elder post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers) help you?

Comment: Can you not return the file stream from the original call and dump it into an iframe?

Comment: Check: "Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server"
 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: @FooBar that looks promising i will test it

Comment: @yuriy636 already saw that i think it is risky as not all browsers are supported

Answer (score 1):

Maybe data-URI can help you for presenting a download link to the user:

```
<a href="data:text/plain,this is some text" download="some-filename.txt" target="_blank">Download<a>
```

[for more information see Mozilla: Data-URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

[credits to the original answer](http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Download-a-file-without-server-request.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering i will test