# Return multiple video files with MultipartFile in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I read that I should not store videos in the database. I should store them on the file system and save in the database their name.
I read some topics like this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/345736

So I have my video files in a folder in my app called `videoDirs`. I would like somehow to return them to the client.

My idea is to return multiple video files for an user using an array of `MultiPartFile` and receive them in AngularJS for the frontend.

Should I do something like this?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/download-video", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public MultipartFile[] handleDownloadVideoRequest(@RequestParam String username) {
            return null;
        }
```

Can you provide me some examples?

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers

Comment: Thanks! I will do it