# How to perform a zero-copy upload and download with WebClient?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Can you perform a zero-copy upload and download with Spring 5 WebFlux using `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient`?

Comment: Based on the documentation of `BodyInserters.fromResource`, it sounds like the following will do a zero-copy upload: `client.post().body(BodyInserters.fromResource(new FileSystemResource(new File("file.txt"))))`. Is that accurate? What about downloads?

Comment: Can only assume a zero-copy download is achievable through: `client.post().exchange().doOnNext(r -> DataBufferUtils.write(r.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()), channel, 0).subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer()))`. However, how can I then block until it is finished consuming? Is this even going to perform a zero-copy download?

Comment: what is zero-copy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, zero-copy is supported for now when posting data from a File-based `Resource`.

So the following looks right:

```
client.post()
      .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(new FileSystemResource(new File("file.txt"))));
```

Now for the reading part, zero-copy is not supported on the reading side right now in Spring Framework; you could create an enhancement issue on jira.spring.io for that.

Your code sample should look like:

```
Flux<DataBuffer> incoming = client.post()
      .retrieve().bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
Mono<Void> writeOperation = DataBufferUtils.write(incoming, channel)
      .map(DataBufferUtils::release)
      .then();
// subscribe to the returned value, which will complete when writing is done
```

Unfortunately, reading data to `DataBuffer` won't do zero-copy as data will be copied in memory. I don't think zero-copy is supported right know on the reading side, so this could be an enhancement request on https://jira.spring.io.

Comment: Does it buffer the entire response? Doesn't buffering cause a block? What's the purpose of `DataBufferUtils.write(Publisher<DataBuffer>, AsynchronousFileChannel, long)` if it buffers the response?

Comment: The entire response is not buffered, it’s written as demand is requested by the reactive pipeline.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bodyToFlux`?

Comment: Please mind that in case of retry you will start writing bytes starting from the beginning of the channel which correlates to the beginning of the file which is basically overwriting anything that you have already downloaded.