# Spring WebClient: How to stream large byte[] to file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

It seems like it the Spring `RestTemplate` isn't able to stream a response directly to file without buffering it all in memory. What is the proper to achieve this using the newer Spring 5 `WebClient`?

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://example.com");
client.get().uri(".../{name}", name).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    ....?
```

I see people have found a few workarounds/hacks to this issue with `RestTemplate`, but I am more interested in doing it the proper way with the `WebClient`.

There are many examples of using `RestTemplate` to download binary data but almost all of them load the `byte[]` into memory.

Comment: You can check already available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988370/download-large-file-from-server-using-rest-template-java-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks but that doesn’t show how to do it using WebClient.

Comment: To solve the problem, you can use RestTemplate of Spring. However Spring 5 introduced Webclient.

Comment: You can also refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740000/how-to-perform-a-zero-copy-upload-and-download-with-webclient

Comment: I don’t think it answers the question. Please create an answer if you think it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring WebFlux Webclient receiving an application/octet-stream file as a Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866547/spring-webflux-webclient-receiving-an-application-octet-stream-file-as-a-mono)

Comment: @K.Nicholas - Do you really think this is a duplicate of that question? For one thing that question doesn't mention streaming directly to the file (not keeping the whole response in memory), which is the main point of my question; and also that question is using Kotlin, not Java.

Comment: @DaveL. - Yea, you're right, should have flagged it as off topic. Let us know when you have something that's giving you problems.

Comment: > Yea, you're right, should have flagged it as off topic.

@K.Nicholas I'm not sure why you keep trying to find a way to undermine my question, but feel free to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and the code of conduct.

Comment: It's more of a request to write the code for you than to answer a question about a problem you are having. No matter, maybe someone here will do it for you. I'm not interested enough to do it myself. Later I saw answers closer than the one I posted but I didn't see anything obvious that included saving the stream as it was incoming. Seems like you'd have to open a file stream as well as the response stream and copy blocks of data between the two.

Comment: Just to clarify for others; that's not really accurate. A link to a specific example, a description + link of the correct api, or, at most, a couple lines of sample code is totally sufficient.

Comment: Any luck with this @DaveL ??

Comment: @JamesGawron No I haven't had a chance to verify the answer below.

Comment: @DaveL. Any below solutions worked for you , without loading file in memory . Actually , Im also facing same problem like you .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With recent stable Spring WebFlux (5.2.4.RELEASE as of writing):

```
final WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://example.com");
final Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = client.get()
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class); // the magic happens here

final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("target/example.html");
DataBufferUtils
        .write(dataBufferFlux, path, CREATE_NEW)
        .block(); // only block here if the rest of your code is synchronous
```

For me the non-obvious part was the `bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)`, as it is currently mentioned within a [generic section about streaming](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-streaming) of Spring's documentation, there is no direct reference to it in the WebClient section.

Comment: DataBuffer basically looks just like a ByteBuffer. I don't see any coordination happening between reader & writer, nor any way to set a size limit on the buffer. How do you know that DataBuffer is reactive (or multi-thread coordinated) & size-bounded?

Comment: Never mind, apparently the stream generates as many DataBuffers as it needs to, each one containing a chunk of the response data. Not sure how the size is determined, maybe in the Netty config. And each DataBuffer is complete when it's emitted to the Flux so no coordination is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! i've wasted hours to understand how to make it works :)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot test whether or not the following code effectively does not buffer the contents of `webClient` payload in memory. Nevertheless, i think you should start from there:

```java
public Mono<Void> testWebClientStreaming() throws IOException {
    Flux<DataBuffer> stream = 
            webClient
                    .get().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
    Path filePath = Paths.get("filename");
    AsynchronousFileChannel asynchronousFileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(filePath, WRITE);
    return DataBufferUtils.write(stream, asynchronousFileChannel)
            .doOnNext(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer())
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> {
                try {
                    asynchronousFileChannel.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) { }
            }).then();
}
```

Comment: FYI, There is a new kid on the block. See [DataBufferUtils#write(Publisher<DataBuffer>, Path, OpenOption...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html#write-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Store the body to a temporary file and consume

```java
static <R> Mono<R> writeBodyToTempFileAndApply(
        final WebClient.ResponseSpec spec,
        final Function<? super Path, ? extends R> function) {
    return using(
            () -> createTempFile(null, null),
            t -> write(spec.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class), t)
                    .thenReturn(function.apply(t)),
            t -> {
                try {
                    deleteIfExists(t);
                } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

#### Pipe the body and consume

```java
static <R> Mono<R> pipeBodyAndApply(
        final WebClient.ResponseSpec spec, final ExecutorService executor,
        final Function<? super ReadableByteChannel, ? extends R> function) {
    return using(
            Pipe::open,
            p -> {
                final Future<Disposable> future = executor.submit(
                        () -> write(spec.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class), p.sink())
                                .log()
                                .doFinally(s -> {
                                    try {
                                        p.sink().close();
                                        log.debug("p.sink closed");
                                    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                                    }
                                })
                                .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer())
                );
                return just(function.apply(p.source()))
                        .log()
                        .doFinally(s -> {
                            try {
                                final Disposable disposable = future.get();
                                assert disposable.isDisposed();
                            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
            },
            p -> {
                try {
                    p.source().close();
                    log.debug("p.source closed");
                } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Isn't this answer a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56096484/839733?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you have access to `RestTemplate` in your current usage of spring, but this one have worked for me.

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate // = ...;

RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> request.getHeaders()
        .setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL));

// Streams the response
ResponseExtractor<Void> responseExtractor = response -> {
    // Here I write the response to a file but do what you like
    Path path = Paths.get("http://some/path");
    Files.copy(response.getBody(), path);
    return null;
};
restTemplate.execute(URI.create("www.something.com"), HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see the code is the same as from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664475/449652. However, that doesn't work with Spring 5 or newer anymore -- see this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19448

Comment: Original poster said he'd want to do it in the proper way, with `Webclient` that's non blocking.

Comment: RestTemplate is soon going to be deprecated.