Issues migrating RestTemplate to WebClient loading response into InputStream
My original code using RestTemplate that would get the byte[] from the response and load into an InputStream to be stream to be streamed back to the calling user.
ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("myApi.com/file/12345", byte[].class);
retrieveResponse.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseEntity.getBody()));

This worked fine but with Spring Boot 3 I moved away from RestTemplate to WebClient and had this code.
responseEntity = webClient.get().uri("myApi.com/file/12345")
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(byte[].class)
                .block();
retrieveResponse.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseEntity.map(HttpEntity::getBody);

This issue is it would fail on files larger than ~256kb and the reason I found through various posts was I was going over the buffer limit because it was loading the whole file into memory. I've never had to mess with that before so I didn't want to band-aid fix it by raising that limit.
With the below code it threw the very clear error:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: writerIndex(754) + minWritableBytes(2358) exceeds maxCapacity(754): PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 754, cap: 754/754, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1179, widx: 1179, cap: 1208))
Flux<DataBuffer> responseBody = webClient
  .get("myApi.com/file/12345")
  .uri()
  .exchangeToFlux(responseEntity -> {
    return responseEntity.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
  });
InputStream inputStream = responseBody.reduce(DataBuffer::write).map(DataBuffer::asInputStream).block();
retrieveResponse.setInputStream(inputStream);

But I assume it's essentially still the same issue.
Some other methods I tried to turn the DataBuffer into an InputStream
// Not sure this even fired
responseBody.subscribe(dataBuffer -> retrieveContentResponse.setInputStream(dataBuffer.asInputStream()));


// I get a 200 back for this but it doesn't write the file to me and just infinitely spins, not really sure what that means.
retrieveResponse.setInputStream(responseBody.blockFirst().asInputStream());

My Response Class
public class RetrieveResponse implements StreamingResponseBody {
  private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
  private InputStream inputStream;

  @Override
  public void writeTo(@NonNull OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
      int bytesRead;
      try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
           OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream)) {
          byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
          while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
              out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
          }
          out.flush();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Exception when writing to output stream", e);
          throw new HttpException("something bad, e);
      }
  }
}

Not sure if there is just an easier way to do this that I'm not aware of, a good bit of legacy code works with InputStreams which is why I can't move away from that part of it.

Please check the accepted answer of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210186/spring-webclient-how-to-stream-large-byte-to-file

@Mar-Z that's writing to a file, the DataBufferUtils doesn't pass it to an InputStream which is what I need to use to stream it back to the end user.
