# Delete tmp file after response?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

My use case:

1. On user request create `tmp` file (I don't really need to create real file, but I need  to have `java.io.File` instance)
2. Process this file
3. Return file and other meta data as json
4. Remove `tmp` file permanently

My code looks like:

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> regeneratePdfTest() throws IOException {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp");

    processFile(tempFile);

    parts.add("file", new HttpEntity<>(new FileSystemResource(tempFile)));
    parts.add("meta-data", new HttpEntity<>(someObject));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(parts, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

(Is this code the best for this case?)

I aware about `File.deleteOnExit()`, but documentation said

> Deletion will be attempted only for normal termination of the virtual machine, as defined by the Java Language Specification

In my case, I want **delete file immediately after response** (file have some private information and I don't want keep them, also safe memory as I don't need this file anymore).

File size can be very large (more than 200MB).

**Update 1:**
If error happen I'd like delete file too.

Comment: Why do you need to create the file. Can't you just write, whatever `processFile(tempFile)` does to file, directly into response?

Comment: I shout take original file, make few changes and output it to user. To make this changes I need to have `java.io.File` so I decided: take original file, make a copy, change copy, output copy, remove copy - it's not really what I need but very similar. I cann't make list of `tmp` files and reuse them, after request I have to remove this `tmp` permanently.

Comment: Btw. how can I output to HttpEntity?

Comment: There are many ways to do this without actual File. See for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers. Why cant you read the original file make the changes in memory and write into response? Is it too big or you need to run special file commands against it?