# Spring mvc download xls with javascript

Tags: javascript, java, excel, spring, spring-mvc

I have a web application in which I want to download a xls file. The controller in spring-boot will return a `HttpServletResponse` via a get request:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/export/{id}", produces = { "multipart/mixed", "multipart/form-data" })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public void export(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    XSSFWorkbook wb = service.export(assessmentId);
    String filename="test.xlsx";
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xlsx");

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        wb.write(bos);
        byte[] barray = bos.toByteArray();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(barray);
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the client I want to export the file to a xls and this is the code:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = objectUrl;
a.download = "test.xlsx";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

I am getting file corrupt when trying to open the xlsx file.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just [send the file as a download from the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)? In HTML use something like `<a href="/export/124875"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>`

Comment: your solution worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't just [send the file as a download from the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)? In HTML use something like

```
<a href="/export/124875"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this one. I solved it using another workaround:
Instead of using ajax, use form to submit. You can surround only the download button like this:

```
<form class="myform" name="myform" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST">    
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
                                                id="download-btn" onclick="submitDl()">Download</button>
                                        </form>
```

submit:

```
function submitDl() {
   window.document.myform.action= your_api_url;
   window.document.myform.encoding='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
   window.document.myform.submit();
}
```

In controller:

```
byte[] barray = bos.toByteArray();
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name_of_your_excel + ".xls");
        response.getOutputStream().write(barray);
        response.flushBuffer();
```

for ppl that has path already do this instead, convert the path to byte[]:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path_of_excel_you_created"));
```

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name_of_your_excel + ".xls");
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
response.flushBuffer();

You can just put void for the return no need to return byte or something...