# File download via Spring shows in browser

Tags: spring, http

I want my web service to return a data file to the caller that they can save on their file system. The problem is that instead of displaying a popup to save the file, it gets displayed in the browser. The following code illustrates the problem:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = "text/plain")
public void testDownload(HttpServletResponse response, Writer responseWriter) {
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        responseWriter.write("Hello World, this is row " + i + "\n");
    }
    responseWriter.flush();
    responseWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
response.setContentType("text/txt");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=HelloWorld.txt");
}
```

Running this results in the returned ten lines being displayed in the browser. I assume I'm missing something in the response but I can't figure out what. The code shown above implements the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers) regarding file download (i.e., use the outputStream, set the ContentType). That suffices to return the data to the caller but that isn't my problem. I need to ensure it doesn't get displayed in the browser but instead the user is prompted to save it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

Comment: I've edited the original question to clarify why this is not a duplicate of the "Downloading a file" question.