# Java creating and writing file to local directory not working

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, file-io

I am trying to write a `Java` code in my `Spring MVC Web Application` that will create a file and save the file to a local directory. My code is as follows:

```
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.csv'").format(new Date());
File file = new File("C:\\my-files\\"+fileName);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
for (Obj obj : objList) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(DATA);
    writer.write(sb.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.write("\r\n");
}
writer.close();
```

This code works for me when I run locally. But when I try to run this code from the server, the file is not getting created. I am not sure if I should be setting some permissions for writing file when the code is run from a server.

I want the file to be created and downloaded to the local drive of the computer from which the web application is accessed. I dont want the file to be saved anywhere else

Comment: is there any exception? what did you get while debugging?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the directory *C:\my-files* on your server? Maybe the file is there...

Comment: maybe server don't have C:\\ drive

Comment: @deHaar, I want to write to a local drive in the computer from which the application is accessed.

Comment: @GeoThomas that makes no sense. basically, if anyone uses your (remote) application, you would be able to start changing things on their workstation?

Comment: @GeoThomas The application will create the file **on the server where the application is executed** because it *thinks locally*. The path will be interpreted as a local one.

Comment: Its not usually recommended to write files on C drive on windows as some people might have read-only access to C drive. try writing on other disks where your program have permission to write

Comment: @Mustahsan, I am ok with any drive on the computer. it is just a data file, a csv. Just trying to save it to local machine

Comment: if possible store file in resource folder

Comment: @deHaar, is there any option to save to the computer rater than the server

Comment: Maybe create the file on the server an make it be downloaded afterwards to have it on a remote machine.

Comment: @GeoThomas you can easily write data on any device the program is running until your program has permissions to write. in this case that computer might not even have C drive?

Comment: @Mustahsan they are not talking about a machine on which the program is running. for instance: I search google.com in my browser, the goal is to have google create a file on my machine. But I don't locally run google, just my browser

Comment: i think he has a local program/ desktop app which will run locally? @GeoThomas

Comment: @Mustahsan that's what he said: as long as he runs it locally, it works. but he doesn't want to run it locally

Comment: that makes no sense, only option he will have to download file on user's machine using octetStream rest response

Comment: one solution is stored in the server then using the help of browser store into a local machine .

Comment: I would delete your question as it is **obviously impossible** for a web server to write  files to a client machine. Imagine the security implications. You can generate the file on the server and stream as the response to a web request and I'm sure you can find plenty of examples of how do do that.

Comment: @ deHaar, is it possible to create my file and then download the file to the client machine? Something like https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-download-file

Comment: i have a question here, is your server in the same windows machine or different? 
the code you have written will only work on local machine where your code is being executed if any other machine it is impossible to do so without making any ftp or sftp connection from client to server this is because of windows security.

Comment: @ Shubham, server is not in the same windows machine

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the servers harddrive is also called C:\ and if the directory my-files exists...

I would generally recommend using relative paths

`File file = new File(fileName);`

Or create your own directory and also use relative paths

```
File file = new File("mydir");
if(!file.exists()) {
  file.mkdir();
}

file = new File(fileName);
... rest of your code
```

Comment: OK... And how does this solve the question? The file still won't be created on the client machine

Comment: The question is not about the code itself, it is about a running the code on a maching and creating the file on another one, which will not work the way tried here.

Comment: @N. Helldorff, how do i initiate a download if I create the file just with filename and the write data to it

Comment: How does somebody initiate a download??

I would recommend you to write a REST Controller

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers