# How to use nio to download file?

Tags: java, nio, file-transfer

I tried to use nio to download photo file by API, but I am not sure how to create a channel to response, is this code correct?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/photosFast/{filename}.jpg", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
...
FileChannel srcChannel = new FileInputStream(src.getAbsolutePath()).getChannel();
FileChannel destChannel = new FileOutputStream(response.getHeader("localtion")).getChannel();
try {
    srcChannel.transferTo(0, srcChannel.size(), destChannel);
} finally {
    srcChannel.close();
    destChannel.close();
}
...
```

Comment: One, you can open a file channel "directly" by using `FileChannel.open`. Two, you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close your channels properly. And finally, you say you're tying to _download_ a file. That implies a remote source, but I only see you opening files. Where is your network access?

Comment: This is an API on server, I want to put file to response.

Comment: You seem to be using a framework (e.g. Spring, JavaEE, etc.). Are you sure you should be manually downloading the file? Or does the framework provide a way to say "here's the file, handle sending it  for me"?

Comment: I am using Spring MVC, do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe [Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/) and/or [`Files.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream)) can help you.

Comment: That is too slow, a 7m file will spend more than 70s to download! So I want to find a faster way...

Comment: The speed performance of downloading a file will be dominated by the network, not by Java.