# Java Rest service with @Produces MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM returns json instead of a pdf file

Tags: java, rest

I have a java rest service that should return a PDF.

This is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response getPdf() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("xxx");
    javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder response = javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file);
    return response.build();
}
```

But the result is always a json instead a file to download or open. Why?

```
{
    "context": {
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": [
                {
                    "type": "application",
                    "subtype": "octet-stream",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "wildcardType": false,
                    "wildcardSubtype": false
                }
            ],
            "Content-Disposition": [
                "attachment; filename=\"12-20200313.pdf\""
            ]
        },
        "configuration": null,
        "entity": "e:\\content\\12-20200313.pdf",
        "entityType": "java.io.File",
        "entityAnnotations": [],
        "entityStream": {
            "closed": false,
            "committed": false
        },
        "length": -1,
        "location": null,
        "language": null,
        "lastModified": null,
        "date": null,
        "acceptableMediaTypes": [
            {
                "type": "*",
                "subtype": "*",
                "parameters": {},
                "quality": 1000,
                "wildcardType": true,
                "wildcardSubtype": true
            }
        ],
        "acceptableLanguages": [
            "*"
        ],
        "committed": false,
        "lengthLong": -1,
        "mediaType": {
            "type": "application",
            "subtype": "octet-stream",
            "parameters": {},
            "wildcardType": false,
            "wildcardSubtype": false
        },
        "allowedMethods": [],
        "requestCookies": {},
        "entityClass": "java.io.File",
        "responseCookies": {},
        "entityTag": null,
        "links": [],
        "stringHeaders": {
            "Content-Type": [
                "application/octet-stream"
            ],
            "Content-Disposition": [
                "attachment; filename=\"12-20200313.pdf\""
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": 200,
    "length": -1,
    "location": null,
    "language": null,
    "lastModified": null,
    "date": null,
    "entity": "e:\\content\\12-20200313.pdf",
    "cookies": {},
    "mediaType": {
        "type": "application",
        "subtype": "octet-stream",
        "parameters": {},
        "wildcardType": false,
        "wildcardSubtype": false
    },
    "allowedMethods": [],
    "metadata": {
        "Content-Type": [
            {
                "type": "application",
                "subtype": "octet-stream",
                "parameters": {},
                "wildcardType": false,
                "wildcardSubtype": false
            }
        ],
        "Content-Disposition": [
            "attachment; filename=\"12-20200313.pdf\""
        ]
    },
    "entityTag": null,
    "links": [],
    "stringHeaders": {
        "Content-Type": [
            "application/octet-stream"
        ],
        "Content-Disposition": [
            "attachment; filename=\"12-20200313.pdf\""
        ]
    },
    "statusInfo": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": [
            {
                "type": "application",
                "subtype": "octet-stream",
                "parameters": {},
                "wildcardType": false,
                "wildcardSubtype": false
            }
        ],
        "Content-Disposition": [
            "attachment; filename=\"12-20200313.pdf\""
        ]
    }
}
```

This service should be called from a classic ASP applicative and then it should save the pdf to disk.
So what I need is that service to return something that could be saved. I also tried to return a base64 string that represent pdf file, then I decode it in the client and save to disk. This works but there are 2 problems here. The first is that I see lots of \r\n inside encoded pdf string that I need to remove before trying to decode it in the client. The second is that it takes minutes for creating pdf file on client.

The preferred solution is to download it but it always returns a json

Thanks

Comment: javax.ws.rs.core.Response Is not a Spring type. Use a FileSystemResource. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10837053/6522707