# Closing the browser tab when download starts

Tags: java, spring-boot, download

I am using a server side API to download a resource from my server. I have direct link to this API in email. When i click on this API from the email then user is redirected to that link in a new tab and download starts.

But the tab that is opened is not getting closed. Is there a way to close this tab as soon as the browser tab.

I dont want to bring a html/javascript code, I want to directly use this link in the browser tab and start the download and then close the tab.

On server side I am using java + spring controllers.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers