# File size without opening the file

Tags: java, filesystems

Is there any way to determine a file's size without having to open it, as provided in the Java platform API (no 3rd party libs)? Also, I need the 64-bit size (which I assume Java would provide to begin with).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116574/java-get-file-size-efficiently

Comment: Zero research effort. Downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, calling [`.length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) on a `File` Object will return its size in bytes.

Comment: That would require constructing an object first opening the file, though; or at least that's what I thought, correct?

Comment: @Bohemian, Grammar Nazi! Just kidding, I was about to fix it myself.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a `new File(...)` for that.

Comment: @Spliff A File object is an abstract pathname. Effectively it is a utility class that wraps a String. No file opening is required.

Comment: @Spliff, There is no significant overhead in constructing a `File` Object. Java won't start reading the file contents when you call `new file()`. `.length()` returns the size reported by the file system.

Answer (score 0):

[`long File.length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29). A `File` object usually represents a path, rather than an open file.

Comment: There's no 'usually' about it.

Answer (score 0):

Without constructing any object for a particular file,How can you use the properties of file class.
OPEN a file means that you are decoding the file data in your compatible format(.txt/.bmp/.pdf etc).
SO you have to first

```
File file=new File("File Name");
```

File Name-->file name of file to which you want to deal.
Then use file.length();

In this phenomenon you are not opening any file,you are just passing reference(address) of the file and retrieving its size.
thats it.
i hope this will beneficial to you.