# Get the number of bytes of a file behind a Java InputStream

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream

As the title says, I need to know how many bytes the file has that's "behind" an InputStream.
I don't want to download all bytes and count (takes to long). I just need to know how many bytes the file has.

Like this:

```
int numberOfBytes = countBytes(inputStream);
```

So, I need an implementation for countBytes(InputStream inputStream)

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116574/java-get-file-size-efficiently

Comment: Do you have access to the file, or just an InputStream to it?

Comment: @Todd I only got the stream which refers to an attachment of an email on an imap server via Javamail API.

Comment: @yock That won't help. The link you posted refers to getting the size from an instanceof File. I only got the stream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other than by consuming the entire stream and counting the bytes, you can't (there's no API for it).

There's the `available()` method, but it quite explicitly doesn't do what you're asking:

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, **many will not**.

If the `InputStream` is associated with a file (and not, say, a socket), perhaps you could use a different API to get its size?

Comment: Nah, I think it's a socket. The input stream refers an attachment of an email via Javamail.

Comment: Hi @Timo have you found any other solution for this ?

Comment: @StrawhatLuffy Sorry, it's so long ago, I don't remember :-)

Answer (score 2):

Could you leverage `skip()` in some way to approximate the size of the file?

```
int bytes = 1024; // Chunk size for skipping. Adjust as necessary
try {
    int skipped = 0;
    while(stream.available()) {
        stream.skip(bytes);
        skipped += bytes;
        // Elided...do something with skipped
    }
} catch(IOException ex) {
    // Handle a skip that's too big
}
```

I'm sure too that you could make this loop smarter and avoid the inevitable `IOException`, but that's an exercise left to the reader.

Comment: As I said before, I need the EXACT byte size

Comment: Then can you skip one byte at a time? Why do you need to know the exact size?

Comment: I am uploading a file to Dropbox and its API needs the exact amount of bytes that I am uploading.