# Java: number of lines in a file without processing it

Tags: java

I need to know the number of lines of a file **before processing it**, because I need to know the number of lines before read it, or in the worst case escenario read it twice..... so I made this code but It not works.. so maybe is just not possible ?

```
InputStream inputStream2 = getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream()));

String line;
int numLines = 0;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        numLines++;
}

TextFileDataCollection dataCollection = new TextFileDataCollection (numLines, 50);

BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream2));

while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(reader2.readLine(), ",");
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextElement());
        }
}
```

Comment: its definitely possible and there are plenty of examples on SO detailing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of lines in a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Well no, @Harry, it is not possible to know the number of lines in a file *without processing it*.  You need to examine the file's contents to count lines, and that's one form of processing.

Comment: You're using the same InputStream twice - after the first loop, it's at the end of the file, so the second loop will not read anything. You need to open **a new InputStream** for the second loop. And you need to **close the old one** after the first loop.

Comment: If you don't want to iterate through the file twice, you could consider redesigning the `TextFileDataCollection` so it doesn't need to know the dataset size up-front.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar question with java code, although it's a bit older:

[Number of lines in a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java)

```
public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChars = 0;
        boolean empty = true;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            empty = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                if (c[i] == '\n') {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here's a reference related to inputstreams specifically:

From [Total number of rows in an InputStream (or CsvMapper) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254158/total-number-of-rows-in-an-inputstream-or-csvmapper-in-java)

"Unless you know the row count ahead of time, it is not possible without looping. You have to read that file in its entirety to know how many lines are in it, and neither InputStream nor CsvMapper have a means of reading ahead and abstracting that for you (they are both stream oriented interfaces).

None of the interfaces that ObjectReader can operate on support querying the underlying file size (if it's a file) or number of bytes read so far.

One possible option is to create your own custom InputStream that also provides methods for grabbing the total size and number of bytes read so far, e.g. if it is reading from a file, it can expose the underlying File.length() and also track the number of bytes read. This may not be entirely accurate, especially if Jackson buffers far ahead, but it could get you something at least."

Comment: Someone indicated that the question is about inputstreams rather than a file.  Unfortunately that means this specific solution probably won't work then.

Answer (score 0):

You write

> I need to know the number of lines of a file before processing it

but you don't present any file in your code; rather, you present only an `InputStream`.  This makes a difference, because indeed **no, you cannot know the number of lines in the input without examining the input to count them**.

If you had a file name, `File` object, or similar mechanism by which you could access the data more than once, then that would be straightforward, but a stream is not guaranteed to be associated with any persistent file -- it might convey data piped from another process or communicated over a network connection, for example.  Therefore, each byte provided by a generic `InputStream` can be read only once.

`InputStream` does provide an API for marking (`mark()`) a position and later returning to it (`reset()`), but stream implementations are not required to support it, and many do not.  Those that do support it typically impose a limit on how far past the mark you can read before invalidating it.  `Reader`s support such a facility as well, with similar limitations.

Overall, if your only access to the data is via an `InputStream`, then your best bet is to process it *without* relying on advance knowledge of the contents.  But if you want to be able to read the data twice, to count lines first, for example, then you need to make your own arrangements to stash the data somewhere in order to ensure your ability to do so.  For example, you might copy it to a temporary file, or if you're prepared to rely on the input not being too large for it then you might store the contents in memory as a `List` of `byte`, `byte[]`, `char`, or `String`.