# Java - Getting The Size of an Object

Tags: java

I am writing a comparator class that compares the file size of one file to another file in the same directory. I am having trouble finding the right documentation to get the file size of a file.

Right now I am looking at the documentation here for getObjectSize:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize(java.lang.Object)

Here is my code, however it does not seem to be working.

```
public class FileComparator implements Comparator {

    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

    }

    static long getObjectSize(Object objectToSize) {

        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(objectToSize);

    }

}

public class Comparison {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("src/Dummy1.pdf");

        System.out.println(FileComparator.getObjectSize(file));

    }

}
```

I get a NullPointerException thrown.

Comment: When you get a NullPointerException, read the stack trace. It'll tell you what is null, and at which line the error occurred. (This goes for many if not all runtime exceptions). I think your specific problem is that `instrumentation` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/instrumentation.shtml

Comment: Also, that method has _nothing_ to do with file size.

Comment: Use `file.length()`. _Returns the length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist._

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116574/java-get-file-size-efficiently

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `file.length()`.

What you are currently trying to get is how much space a `file` Object takes in the RAM, which is **not** what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to initialize the `instrumentation` to get rid of NullPointerException

Try this:

```
 public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    instrumentation = o2;
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

 }
```

Also use `file.length()` as you want to know the space which your file object takes